# Cloudera Manager ZooKeeper warning. "outdated configuration."

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I use Cloudera CDH4.

ZooKeeper servers are: zook01, zook02, zook03, zook04, zook05

The zook05 server crashed.

I deleted zook05 in Cloudera Manager.

So for zook05 I reinstalled the OS and put zook05 back into the zookeeper service.

I saw the following warning at 4 of the zookeeper nodes(zook01 ~ zook04):

> outdate configuration. restart the service(or the instance) for the changes to take effect"

I have confirmed HBase's quorum.

The ZooKeeper quorum set to HBase is missing zook05.

How can I get rid of ZooKeeper's warning?

How do I get HBase to recognize zook05?

Answer (score 2):

Restart your ZooKeepers.

The warning is clear.  Most likely, when you deleted the ZooKeeper instance, the zoo.cfg was changed with `zook05` removed.  After, adding it back in again, the other ZooKeepers config file is considered outdated even if they will have the same configuration as they did prior to the deletion.

Comment: I restarted four servers one by one. Warnings have disappeared from the zookeeper service. But I am still missing zook5 from hbase's quorum list. Can I restart the entire zookeeper service? Do I have to restart hbase?

Comment: You should restart HBase after the zookeeper warnings have gone away.